# Ubuntu 20.04 weird problems on mariadb-server-10.3 upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, mariadb

I have just performed a dist-upgrade on ubuntu 20.04 server and got stuck on mariadb-server-10.3

The apt process hung on this package and after 20 minutes waiting I have killed the process. After that, I checked mariadb and it was running with v. 10.3 but apt is still claiming for configuration:

```
dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mariadb-server-10.3 (1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

Hanging forever. But if I check installed packages, I get this:

```
dpkg -l | grep maria*
ii  mariadb-client-10.3                  1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                 amd64        MariaDB database client binaries
ii  mariadb-client-core-10.3             1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                 amd64        MariaDB database core client binaries
ii  mariadb-common                       1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                 all          MariaDB common metapackage
iU  mariadb-server                       1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                 all          MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
iF  mariadb-server-10.3                  1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                 amd64        MariaDB database server binaries
ii  mariadb-server-core-10.3             1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                 amd64        MariaDB database core server files
```

It won't be a problem, except that from now on, every time I need to update a package/system I going through this hanging problem:

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.3
 mariadb-server
```

How to fix?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices releases that can use *snap* packages only. Specialist releases are usually used headless, so I'd recommend a desktop release and not a device release (ie. *yy.mm* format release and not *yy* based).   Ubuntu 20 implies Ubuntu Core 20; which cannot use the `dpkg` or `apt` commands - it's a *snap* only system.

Comment: come on @guiverc. It's 20.04 server. I forgot the month release because I was in a hurry. Thank you for the lesson.
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

Comment: I edited the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to reinstall to fix. Obviously if you can do a backup first, do one!

`sudo apt remove mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3 mariadb-client mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common`

Note: I didn't have to restore any of my databases. I saw the following message while running the command above:
`dpkg: warning: while removing mariadb-server-core-10.3, directory '/usr/share/mysql' not empty so not removed`

So if you want to do a backup, which you should there are no excuses, you can do so from ('/var/lib/mysql') the your databases should be stored.

Reinstall/restore MariaDB:
`sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client`

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: MySql databases are in /var/lib/mysql, not in /usr/share/mysql !

Comment: @FabioMarzocca
Good catch, thank you! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had to the existing mysql-server on the server. This is because I have no need for MySQL on the server

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Then I re-installed MariaDB Server

To install

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

To setup

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had mySQL installed before, and your syslog shows

```
AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
```

no purging, reinstalling or the like will help.

A lingering AppArmor profile will prevent mariaDB from successfully starting.

So effectively anyone who wants to switch from mySQL to mariaDB on Debian or Ubuntu will fail miserably (could it be there is some Oracle maintainer involved in the package creation ? ;-) )

This is known since 18.04, including a fix, and not fixed until now.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.1/+bug/1806263

```
echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" > /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

will fix it. Afterwards, mariaDB can be installed and/or the service can be started.